# alert when clicking on disabled tag

Tags: jquery

i disable any input and select with this code:

```
 var elements = ['#lbl1' ,'#lbl2','#lbl3','#lbl4','#lbl5','#lbl6','#lbl7'];
 jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
     $(elements[element]).attr('disabled', true);   
 });
```

now, i want to if user clicking on the disabled tags alert for user:

```
var elements = ['#lbl1' ,'#lbl2','#lbl3','#lbl4','#lbl5','#lbl6','#lbl7'];
 jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
   $(elements[element]).click(function{
   if ( $(elements[element]).attr() == 'disabled')  alert('DISABLED');  
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the open/close parenthesis on the click function:

```
   $(elements[element]).click(function() {
```

Why not combine the two functions?

```
var elements = ['#lbl1' ,'#lbl2','#lbl3','#lbl4','#lbl5','#lbl6','#lbl7'];
 jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
     $(elements[element]).attr('disabled', true).click(function(){
        alert('DISABLED');
     });
 });
```

Because you are chaining the bind-to-click-function onto the end of the set-attribute function you do not need to run the each loop multiple times.

Comment: You are setting all his elements to disabled instead of checking if it's disabled

Comment: He is doing that in the first loop. In the second loop they should all be disabled.

Comment: nvm.. maybe that's what he wants.. I'm not even sure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mouse events like **click will work for Disabled Elements**.

If you want the code , it can be written this way... But it won't fire on disabled elements.

Check for **true** instead of disabled..

```
  $(function() {
    $('[id^="lbl"]').attr('disabled', true);

    $('[id^="lbl"]').on('click', function(){
        if( $(this).attr('disabled') === true){
              alert('DISABLED');
          }
    });
  });
```

You do not need to assign the click event inside of $.each loop..

You can directly assign the event by using the **id^=lbl** , Which check for all elements whose id start with lbl .

Comment: i'm using jquery-1.8.2 but .prop property not working in my code

Comment: Also when the field is disabled,, the click event will not work

Comment: now,`$('[id^="lbl"]').on('click', function(){` not work for me, why?

Answer (score 0):

This would be SO much easier if you put a class on all the elements you want to disable. You can then turn this into a one-liner.

```
$(".disabled-element").prop("disabled", true);
```

To check if the label is disabled you would then also not need a loop:

```
$(".disabled-element").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("disabled")) {
        alert("disabled");
    }
});
```

Note though that `disabled` form elements will not raise a click event in most browsers, labels should be fine though.

Comment: this code not work for me: `$('[id^="lbl"]').prop("disabled", true);
$('[id^="lbl"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("disabled")) {
        alert("disabled");
    }
});`